# Why my code is wrong for large input in subarray?

Tags: python, arrays

My code is working fine for small inputs but throwing error for large inputs:

```
#User function Template for python3
#Function to find a continuous sub-array which adds up to a given number.
class Solution:
    def subArraySum(self,arr, n, s): 
       #Write your code here\
       i=0
       j=0
       a=[]
       sum=arr[0]
   
       while(i<n):
           if(sum == s):
               a.append(i+1)
               a.append(j+1)
               return a
            
           elif((sum<s) and j<n):
               j+=1
               sum+=arr[j]
                
           elif(sum>s):
               sum-=arr[i]
               i+=1
       a.append(-1)
       return a
```

Error:

```
Runtime Error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/381d13fbccd456f6ad3f1e6fd0fe5554.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/381d13fbccd456f6ad3f1e6fd0fe5554.py", line 43, in main
    ans=ob.subArraySum(A, N, S)
  File "/home/381d13fbccd456f6ad3f1e6fd0fe5554.py", line 20, in subArraySum
    sum+=arr[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Expected Output:

Sample input: (error)

```
74 665
142 112 54 69 148 45 63 158 38 60 124 142 130 179 117 36 191 43 89 107 41 143 65 49 47 6 91 130 171 151 7 102 194 149 30 24 85 155 157 41 167 177 132 109 145 40 27 124 138 139 119 83 130 142 34 116 40 59 105 131 178 107 74 187 22 146 125 73 71 30 178 174 98 113
```

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pG2H.png)

Answer (score 0):

The logic you followed is a bit flawed, If `i < n` and `sum < s` , `j` will get the value of `len(arr)`, because `j+=1` is executed before the calculation of the sum.

Comment: To see this, just print the values of `j` and you will find out that the last value that `j` takes will be out of range.